# Get wrong bitmap when using jpos to pack iso8583 message?

Tags: java, jpos

I'm starting to use jpos for my application. I need my application to send a message iso8583 (ver 1987) to server and receive the response.

This 's my code:

```
InputStream is = PackagerFactory.class.getResourceAsStream("iso87ascii.xml");
ISOPackager packager = new GenericPackager(is);
ISOMsg m = new ISOMsg();
m.setMTI("0820");
m.set(7, "0319174039");
m.set(11, "639530");
m.set(15, "0319"); 
m.set(24, "001");
m.set(64, "6038f060aba137a5b0efb4cc538416c8");
m.setPackager(packager);
byte b[] = m.pack();
String s = new String(b);
```

Value of "s": 082002220100000000010000031917403963953003190016038f060aba137a5b0efb4cc538416c8

So:
0820 is MTI 
02220100000000010000 is Bitmap.

There some thing I don't understand:
1. About the bitmap:
Why is length of the bitmap 20, but, its length is specified in the file config "iso87ascii.xml" is 16?

Here is iso87ascii.xml's content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE isopackager SYSTEM "genericpackager.dtd">

<!-- ISO 8583:1987 (ASCII) field descriptions for GenericPackager -->

<isopackager>
  <isofield
      id="0"
      length="4"
      name="MESSAGE TYPE INDICATOR"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="1"
      length="16"
      name="BIT MAP"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BITMAP"/>
  <isofield
      id="2"
      length="19"
      name="PAN - PRIMARY ACCOUNT NUMBER"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  ...
  <isofield
      id="7"
      length="14"
      name="TRANSMISSION DATE AND TIME"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
...
  <isofield
      id="11"
      length="6"
      name="SYSTEM TRACE AUDIT NUMBER"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
....
  <isofield
      id="15"
      length="4"
      name="DATE, SETTLEMENT"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
...
  <isofield
      id="24"
      length="3"
      name="NETWORK INTERNATIONAL IDENTIFIEER"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
.....
  <isofield
      id="64"
      length="32"
      name="MESSAGE AUTHENTICATION CODE FIELD"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>

</isopackager>
```

2.About header of message:
I wanna send a message with format:

```
Package header + Package body
```

Package header: four ASCII characters header indicating package body length. 
Package body: a 8583 message

So, how can I do that with JPOS?

Please help,

Thank in advance,

Comment: ISO 8583 is a binary format; why do you print it as a `String`?

Answer (score 3):

Your field 7 packager is

```
<isofield id="7" length="14" name="TRANSMISSION DATE AND TIME" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
```

You set it to:

```
m.set(7, "0319174039");
```

The packager pads it to 14 wide (0's added on the left). Try this and you will notice it:

```
Logger l = new Logger();
l.addListener(new SimpleLogListener(System.out));
 ISOPackager packager = new GenericPackager("iso87ascii.xml");
 packager.setLogger(l, "");

 ISOMsg m = new ISOMsg();
 m.setMTI("0820");
 m.set(7, "0319174039");
 m.set(11, "639530");
 m.set(15, "0319");
 m.set(24, "001");
 m.set(64, "6038f060aba137a5b0efb4cc538416c8");
 m.setPackager(packager);
 byte b[] = m.pack();

 m.dump(System.out,"");
 m.unpack(b);
 System.out.println(ISOUtil.hexdump(b));
 m.dump(System.out,"");
```

What you call package length header is what jpos does through channels. So you pass your iso msg through a channel that append/prepends length to the message and transmits it.

```
 ASCIIChannel channel = new ASCIIChannel("127.0.0.1",7654,packager);//IP port to connect to, and packager will be used to pack the message and send it
 channel.setLogger(l, "Test");
 channel.send(m);
```

See also the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jpos-users/mDDIMYb0E9Y) thread.